# Storing a double array as NSNumber

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have a variable `double * data = malloc(sizeof(double))` in objectiveC;

I am using this variable as an double array like data[] to store some data. Now I want to add this data variable (which is an double* array) as an object `NSNumber in iOS. Any idea how I can turn it into iOS object like`NSNumber`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSData` to wrap an arbitrary byte buffer into an Objective-C object.

Use `dataWithBytes:length:` to create an `NSData` object from your double array, and `bytes:` or `getBytes:length:` to retrieve the data bytes back from the `NSData` object.

Comment: this seems to be solution for my problem. Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mundi's answer, try this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfDoublearray; i++) { // as premitive DataType array needs predefined length
    [array  addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:data[i]]];
}
```

Here `data` is array of `double` (that you used).

Comment: As I mention u first need to look at Mundi's Answer. :)

Comment: i have already looked at that. Seems like there is no shortcut solution for that.

Comment: That would be a pretty long statement for a 3000 element array.

Comment: @HotLicks I think Now it makes more sense, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot turn an array of primitives into one `NSNumber`. This does not make any sense.

You can, however, turn an array of doubles into an array of `NSNumbers`. Iterate through your double* array and add each number to an `NSMutableArray` as `NSNumber` using its class method `numberWithDouble:`.

Comment: aha my bad luck. i want that array of double as stored as a single object in NSArray and wants to retrieve it back to double[] at some other point. Is somehow it is possible without an array of  NSNumber ?

Comment: Why? You can easily store the NSArray in user preferences or plist files, even as an element of another array.